# Custom domain with Google App Engine app

Tags: google-app-engine

I have setup my GAE app with my registered domain. And from the Admin page:

```
Your users can access myapp at: 
https://myapp.appspot.com
http://www.myapp.com
```

**Note: app name is not actual*

However the problem is when `www.myapp.com` is accessed the URL changes to `myapp.appspot.com`

What could be missing?

Comment: httpS? Did you do that from Google Apps?

Comment: I guess it just needed some time to propagate it works fine now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you have a previous setup with your domain?

I suspect that your DNS cache is redirecting you.

Do `curl -i http://www.myapp.com`

See if it's a redirect and what kind

Also check at your domain provider to check to point the GAE DNS servers and not use a redirect

Also you can try with wifi off on your mobile to see if it helps with the intermediate DNS caches.